# Integrate $\int\frac{1}{x^2-(\sqrt{b+1})^2}\text{d}x$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate the following

$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2-(\sqrt{b+1})^2}\text{d}x
$$

I got

$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+1}}\text{log}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+x}{\sqrt{b+1}-x}\right)\
$$

but apparently Matlab thinks it's

$$
-\text{tanh}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{\sqrt{b+1}}\right]/\sqrt{b+1}\
$$

I'm pretty sure they're identical but the lower expression is more convenient for my calculations. What identity should I use to arrive at the lower expression?

Edit: typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, we let $k=\sqrt{b+1}$. Using two methods yields two primitives which differs by a constant.

For the first answer,  using partial fractions, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{1}{x^2-k^2} & =\frac{1}{2 k} \int\left(\frac{1}{x-k}-\frac{1}{x+k}\right) d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2 k} \ln \left|\frac{x-k}{x+k}\right|+C\\
OR& =-\frac{1}{2 k} \ln \left|\frac{x+k}{x-k}\right|+C_1
\end{aligned}
$$

For the second answer, we use the substitution $x=\tanh \theta$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{x^2-k^2} & =-\int \frac{1}{k^2 \operatorname{sech}^2 \theta} \cdot k\operatorname{sech}^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =-\frac{1}{k} \int 1 d \theta \\
& =-\frac{\theta}{k}+C \\
& =-\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{k}+C_2
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB most likely used a trig substitution of some sort. For integrals of the type

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 - a^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

or generally anything involving $x^2 - a^2$ or especially $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$, several potential substitutions can apply:

- $x = a \sec \theta$ (the "standard" one from Calculus II)
- $x = a \csc \theta$
- $x = a \cosh u$
- $x = a \coth u$

Each of these try to leverage the Pythagorean identities for ordinary or hyperbolic trig functions:

- $\sec^2 \theta - 1 = \tan^2 \theta$
- $\csc^2 \theta - 1 = \cot^2 \theta$
- $\cosh^2 u - \sinh^2 u = 1$
- $\coth^2 u - 1 = \operatorname{csch}^2 u$

My suspicion is MATLAB used the fourth of these in each list, alongside other identities like

$$\operatorname{arcoth}(x) = \operatorname{artanh} \left( \frac 1 x \right)$$

to find the integral.

Notably, the equivalence of the answers likely follows by the identity

$$\operatorname{artanh}(x) = \frac 1 2 \ln \left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)$$

which holds for $|x|<1$, and one uses $\operatorname{arcoth}(x)$ for the case $|x|>1$. I'm not really sure off-hand how to handle the factor of $\cos(x)$, though.

Answer (score 0):

> $$
> \int\frac{1}{x^2-(\sqrt{b+1})^2}\text{d}x
> $$
>
> I got
>
> $$
> \frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+1}}\text{log}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+x}{\sqrt{b+1}-x}\right)\
> $$

Note you miss a minus sign here, it should be

$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2-(\sqrt{b+1})^2}\text{d}x={\color{red}-}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+1}}\text{log}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+x}{\sqrt{b+1}-x}\right)+C
$$

> but apparently Matlab thinks it's
>
> $$
> -\text{tanh}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{\sqrt{b+1}}\right]/\sqrt{b+1}\
> $$

Note your $\cos(x)$ should be $x$

$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2-(\sqrt{b+1})^2}\text{d}x=-\text{tanh}^{-1}\left[\frac{{\color{red}x}}{\sqrt{b+1}}\right]/\sqrt{b+1}+C
$$

Use the expression for the inverse hyperbolic tangent function:

$$\text{arctanh}(z)=\frac{1}2\ln\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$

Start from your result:

$$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b+1}}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{b+1}+x}{\sqrt{b+1}-x}\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{b+1}}}{1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{b+1}}}\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{b+1}}\right)$$